# Sudden, inexplicable rep-jump

Tags: support, reputation

I logged into StackOverflow today and I had 3,053 points.  After a short while, I refreshed the page and I had 3,108 points.  A quick check of my [rep-history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/135978?tab=reputationhistory#tab-top) reveals no sudden upsurge of votes on my questions or newly-accepted answers to explain the jump.  While I do not object to additional reputation *per se* I am wondering what caused the jump.  Is there any way I can dig deeper to make sure that my rep-jump was caused by my good answers rather than by a bug?

**Clarification:** it wasn't when I first signed in that the jump happened. I checked a few questions and a couple of tags before I left it to sit for a while, and for part of that time it showed me a rep of 3,053. It changed over after a couple of page loads to yesterday's 3083, and then jumped again when the question Lance pointed out was up-voted and accepted.

Checking https://stackoverflow.com/reputation I see this, for the past two days:

```
-- 2010-05-15 rep +15   = 3053      
 2   2851608 (10)
 2   2851608 (10)
 2   2851608 (10)
-- 2010-05-17 rep +30   = 3083      
 2   2851608 (10)
 1   2851608 (15)
-- 2010-05-18 rep +25   = 3108
```

Comment: Does an audit at http://stackoverflow.com/reputation give you any information?

Comment: Maybe you were suddenly, inexplicably awesome?

Comment: @ccornet; Very nice! That's precisely the kind of granular detail I was looking for.

Comment: @beska Thanks!  That is possible, but it's not **particularly** probable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You had an old page cached, then you renewed to a current page.  This happens to me all the time, I always renew the SO pages when I sign on to them.  So you did gain the rep, but it could have happened a while ago.

My guess would be the 55 points from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851580/how-do-i-format-an-email-for-gmail/2851608#2851608).

You can hit the envelope up top, then hit the reputation tab, and look at today and yesterday.

Comment: That was my first thought too ... however, it wasn't when I **first** signed in that the jump happened.  I checked a few questions and a couple of tags before I left it to sit for a while, and for part of that time it showed me a rep of 3,053. It changed over after a couple of page loads to yesterday's 3083, and then jumped again when the question you pointed out was up-voted and accepted. (Apologies though, the way I worded the question made it sound like I just logged in, sat for a while and then refreshed the page).